# Simple html dom parser. Parsing all texts links without images links

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I use this code for parsing url, in output I have all texts links and all links images, but I need only texts links. How can I do it?

```
$linkbox = array();
foreach($html -> find('a') as $link)
{
  linkbox[] = $link -> outertext;
}
```

Comment: Try capturing `$link->href`?

Comment: not work, It would be too easy

Answer (score 0):

PHP DomDocument, right? If yes - maybe you need textContent property:

```
linkbox[] = $link->textContent;
```

or, if you need href:

```
linkbox[] = $link->getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: i have array links but i need only text links, without images links

Comment: You need to remove image tag from text, or remove all links with img tag? If second - you can use $link->childNode to find `img` tag, and not work with link if it found.